# How to perform Zooming with CHtmlEditCtrl in MFC

Tags: mfc, visual-c++, dhtml, mshtml

Can anyone help me to perform zooming on CHtmlEditCtrl ?

I displayed my html document on CHtmlEditCtrl.
Now I want my edit control to display same html document with different zooming level.
I saw this feature in InternetExplorer8.
Now I need to add this zooming feature to my MFC application.

Answer (score 0):

[ExecWB(OLECMDID_ZOOM, 0, &vFontSize, NULL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046(VS.85).aspx#use_ExecWB)

Comment: Thanks,
But This code will only change the font size of the page.
Means it provides zooming of the page like firefox performs when mouse-scroll on holding ctrl button.
I need zooming that is provided in InternetExplorer7-and-later.
In bottom-right corner there is a zooming combo box.

Comment: OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM OLECMDIDF_OPTICAL_ZOOM_NOPERSIST?

Answer (score 0):

Use OPTICAL_ZOOM as so;

```
VARIANT vaZoomFactor;
VariantInit (&vaZoomFactor);
V_VT(&vaZoomFactor) = VT_I4;
V_I4(&vaZoomFactor) = 50; //-- in this case, 50%
browserCtrl.ExecWB (OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, &vaZoomFactor, NULL);
```